# Floaty FOOTERITIS?

Tags: css

When I add and remove controls inside the content div/fieldset, the footer comes up into the content area.

Not sure what to do.

Also, I am probably using a really old hack to make that left side menu bar go all the way down.

Helps!

http://tcraider.engl.ttu.edu/uwcdev/test/client_home.asp

Answer (score 1):

You might like to look into http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/.

Their solution is cross-browser, well-tested, and I've been using it on my app for months.

Comment: I'm curious: Why is this better than just using `position:fixed`?

Comment: @NathanArthur - my understanding is that the site I mentioned allows the footer to slide down underneath the content when it's longer than one page length, and it stays at the bottom of the visible page when the content is short.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the explanation! +1